# BackEnd Pagination with ngb-Pagination maxSize value Incorrect

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-bootstrap

This is my Pagination call

```
<ngb-pagination class="d-flex justify-content-end" 
  (pageChange)="changePg({pgNum: $event})" 
  [maxSize]="pagination?.totalPageCnt"
  size="sm"
  rotate="true"
  [page]="pagination?.page" 
  [collectionSize]="pagination?.MatchedCnt">
</ngb-pagination>
```

This is My response from the server with the Pagination information:

```
pagination:{
    page: 1
    pageSize: 50
    totalPageCnt: 11
    matchedCnt: 532
    sentCnt: 50
}
```

this is the resulting Page. I don't understand why the MaxSize value is applying in correctly...54 is nowhere in my response or being called anywhere...
[image]

Ignore the drop down that's to show the page size and works. So does the page number the values are being passed correctly. However, maxSize of the pagination display is way off it's supposed to be 11 but sits at 54. The values aren't being manipulated anywhere. I receive the pagination object and display the values in my template.

Comment: 532 elements, 10 elements per page, that makes 54 pages. Read the API documentation and the examples to use the properties **correctly**. Especially, the documentation of maxSize and pageSize.

Comment: but I am displaying 50 elements per page. It can be 54 at the min value of 10 items per page. But the response gives the values for pagination to show including the number of pages so why does it stay at 54? when the value provided to page size is 11 (totalpageCnt)

Comment: You're displaying 50 elements per page, but you're not telling that to the ngb-pagination component, so it assumes its default value, 10. Again, read the documentation. Especially, the documentation of maxSize and pageSize. What does the documentation of these two inputs say?

Comment: I see, I have been reading the documentation and acting accordingly. When I try to add page size it shrinks the number of pages to just 2. Thank you for clarifying I will try it again and see if I missed something!

Comment: you were right...I was defining my values wrong... thank you.